# Как изменить цвет бэкграунда у кнопки в yandex map?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

```
  ymaps.ready(init);
        function init () {
            var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [59.93772, 30.313622],
                zoom: 10,
                controls: []
            })

            var firstbutton = new ymaps.control.Button({
                data: {
                    content: "кнопка",
                 

                },
                options: {
              
                    maxWidth: [28, 150, 178],
                    

                },


            });


            map.controls.add(firstbutton);

        }
```

Как поменять задний фон у кнопки, чтобы он стал не белый, а там красный например?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В песочнице Яндекс есть подходящий для вашего случая пример https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/button_layout

Все настройки кнопки указываются в блоке **style** файла **button_layout.html** для класса **.my-button**. Цвет фона задан там же:

```
    .my-button {
        background: #eee;
    }
```

Просто задайте тут нужный вам цвет.